# The best way for converting the models

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, service, architecture

I have controller layer of my web application which should run some action from external service and send ExternalServiceDTO. My controller layer works with ControllerDTO. I have domain model for ControllerDTO - it's DomainModel with domain service DomainModelService.

What will be the best way for converting the models? I see 2 options

1. ControllerDTO -> DomainModel -> ExternalServiceDTO In this way we
   are converting to domain model at first, before preparing external
   dto. External dto will be created from DomainModelService.
2. ControllerDTO -> ExternalServiceDTO In this way, we just preparing
   external dto from controller dto

Please advice

Comment: Well, if the domain model is your central model and contains all the data needed for the external service then I'd vote for option 1. You'll probably need the conversion between ControllerDTO and DomainModel anyway so the only thing you'd need to add is the conversion between DomainModel and the external DTO. That would decouple controller and external service and allow you to easily add other controllers and/or external services without the need to add conversions for all possible permutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library Model Mapper.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

To convert DTO to Entity you can user this:

```
      private Entity toEntity(DTO dto) throws ParseException {
          Entity entity = modelMapper.map(dto, Entity.class);
          return entity;
     }
```

At your controller you should to inject the Mapper, by:

```
     @Autowired
     private ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this solution with the `@Builder` annotation (Lombok) that implements the builder design pattern. This is how I do this operation in my everyday coding life.

```
public RecordingMetaDataDto toDto(RecordingMetaData metaData) {
    return RecordingMetaDataDto.builder()
            .id(metaData.getId())
            .filename(metaData.getFilename())
            .bucket(metaData.getS3Resource().getBucket())
            .s3key(metaData.getS3Resource().getS3key())
            .durationInMinutes(metaData.getDurationInMinutes())
            .startTime(metaData.getStartTime())
            .endTime(metaData.getEndTime())
            .deviceIdentifier(metaData.getDeviceIdentifier())
            .processingStatus(metaData.getProcessingStatus())
            .storageClass(metaData.getStorageClass())
            .createdAt(metaData.getAudit().getCreatedAt())
            .createdBy(metaData.getAudit().getCreatedBy())
            .modifiedAt(metaData.getAudit().getModifiedAt())
            .modifiedBy(metaData.getAudit().getModifiedBy())
            .build();
}
```

Lombok dependency for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```